# How do I suppress a variable level with no observation in table?

Tags: r

In my dataset, I have "Sex" variable with 7 labels/categories as follows-

```
"Male"
"Female"
"Female‐Not Preg" 
"Fem‐Preg 1st Tri"
"Fem‐Preg 2nd Tri"
"Fem‐Preg 3rd Tri" and
"Not Available (SEX)"
```

I am simply looking at a table- `table(data$Sex)`
which provides me the following -

[image]

What to do so that these labels with no observation do not get printed?

Comment: perhaps `table(droplevels(data$Sex))` ; if not can you add the results of `dput(data$Sex)` to your question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming factor `fac` use `droplevels` as in this example code:

```
fac <- factor(c("b", "a"), levels = letters)
table(fac)
## fac
## a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
## 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

table(droplevels(fac))  
##
## a b 
## 1 1
```